# How to disable the opening of windows explorer after scan ?

Tags: windows-7, scanning, picture-import-wizard

How can i disable the opening of windows explorer after importing the pictures from camera ?

Answer (score 0):

In this [MSFT](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows7/change-settings-for-importing-pictures-and-videos) help search for keyword, "View the pictures and videos in Windows Explorer after they're imported" and do as it suggests.